# Kohana 3.3 hello world does not work

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

I keep getting the following error when i navigate to: `http://localhost:81/framework/`:

**Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL framework was not found on this server.**

[image]

**My Controller:**

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No Direct Script Access');

Class Controller_Welcome extends Controller_Template
{
    public $template = 'site';

    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->template->message = 'hello, world!';
    }
}
```

My **bootstrap.php** file looks like this:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

// -- Environment setup --------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Initialize Kohana, setting the default options.
 *
 * The following options are available:
 *
 * - string   base_url    path, and optionally domain, of your application   NULL
 * - string   index_file  name of your index file, usually "index.php"       index.php
 * - string   charset     internal character set used for input and output   utf-8
 * - string   cache_dir   set the internal cache directory                   APPPATH/cache
 * - integer  cache_life  lifetime, in seconds, of items cached              60
 * - boolean  errors      enable or disable error handling                   TRUE
 * - boolean  profile     enable or disable internal profiling               TRUE
 * - boolean  caching     enable or disable internal caching                 FALSE
 * - boolean  expose      set the X-Powered-By header                        FALSE
 */
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/kohana/',
));

/**
 * Attach the file write to logging. Multiple writers are supported.
 */
Kohana::$log->attach(new Log_File(APPPATH.'logs'));

/**
 * Attach a file reader to config. Multiple readers are supported.
 */
Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_File);

/**
 * Enable modules. Modules are referenced by a relative or absolute path.
 */
Kohana::modules(array(
    // 'auth'       => MODPATH.'auth',       // Basic authentication
    // 'cache'      => MODPATH.'cache',      // Caching with multiple backends
    // 'codebench'  => MODPATH.'codebench',  // Benchmarking tool
    // 'database'   => MODPATH.'database',   // Database access
    // 'image'      => MODPATH.'image',      // Image manipulation
    // 'minion'     => MODPATH.'minion',     // CLI Tasks
    // 'orm'        => MODPATH.'orm',        // Object Relationship Mapping
    // 'unittest'   => MODPATH.'unittest',   // Unit testing
    // 'userguide'  => MODPATH.'userguide',  // User guide and API documentation
    ));

/**
 * Set the routes. Each route must have a minimum of a name, a URI and a set of
 * defaults for the URI.
 */
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

I have also tried creating a `view` called `site.php` located in the following directory:
`http://localhost/framework/application/views/site.php`

**site.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>We've got a message for you!</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {font-family: Georgia;}
            h1 {font-style: italic;}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?php echo $message; ?></h1>
        <p>We just wanted to say it! :)</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get the following error when i navigate to site.php:

[image]

Comment: I am also using WAMP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set proper path (which is `/framework/`) in your bootstrap.php (`'base_url' => /framework/` in Kohana::init part) and .htaccess RewriteBase (`RewriteBase /framework/`)

Comment: Any ideas how i can call my controller with a view? I still get an error with the undefined variable.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. By default you should be able to call your controller actions now like this: yoururl/controllername/actionname. If the action is skipped then index one is used. You can create and output views from there.

Comment: $view = View::factory('site'); $this->response->body($view); should work

Comment: Im also confused with all the if statements in the index.php file. Do i actually need all that for every page in my site?

Comment: In if i create a new page called, `new.php` and then paste the following: `<?php

$view = Welcome('site'); $view->render();

?>
` it should display in my page?

Comment: You shouldn't actually edit index.php. You get the framework with all HMVC you usually need.

Comment: No, you don't understand. You don't need to create any pages of your own. You create Controllers with Actions in them. Then you call them using the routing rules you specified in the bootstrap.php. Inside the actions you can create views from your view files, assign variables, output the results etc. Read more about MVC and HMVC

Comment: I see. Sorry im soo used to flat php! I see so the business logic is in the controller and the view is just my HTML..

Comment: You'll get used to it and it will solve many problems for you. Basically you're right - views are for visible part of the system and the controllers are sets of actions that take care of many other things

Comment: Last question? are you part of the team that created the framework?

Comment: No, but I've built several projects based on Kohana 2.x and Kohana 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the basestrap.php i didnt set the base URL:

**Before:**

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/kohana/',
));
```

**After:**

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/framework/',
));
```